# iOS Code Signing Identity mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

Whenever I try to archive my project, this is what I get : [image]

But I never selected the Distribution Profile in Build Settings.

[image]

So I deleted every **Certificates & Profiles** from '**Keychain Access**' and still no luck.

What might be the issue causing this? Thanks

Comment: Xcode->preferences tab -> Accounts -> View Details -> Refresh certificates and provisional profiles

Comment: why are you using development profile ? and if the certificate is also dev certificate? –  Muhammad Adnan 53 secs ago   edit

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I was trying to send out test build. But somehow the Distribution Certificate is creating the problem

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Yes. The certificate is a dev one.

Comment: Now you can not create ipa using development profile . Use adhoc or distribution one

Answer (score 1):

try to regenerates the both developer and distribution certificates i think your private key was deleted from your system
this tutorial will help you to step by step solution
[here](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/generating_certificate.png)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while archive project, so for that I had created the AdHoc certificate and its work.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Code Signing Identity` section does not look fine to me. IMO you need to set your `iPhone Distribution` identity (instead of `iPhone Developer` as seen in your screenshot) in build settings for your `Release` config.

You cannot Archive with `Developer profile/certificate` (unless you do some hacky tricks).

If you really need to have a IPA with `Developer profile`:
Build the project. Find your **xxx.app** file under **Products** folder. Show it in **Finder**. Put that file under a new folder called **Payload**. Compress **Payload** folder. Now you have a **zip** file. Rename it and change its extension to **.ipa**, Finder will give you a warning but nevermind it. Now you have a running ipa signed with `Developer profile`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provision your XCode with a developer profile. For this, you have to follow the procedure for it. To find it, I advise you to search on line "iOS provisioning developer profile" or something like that. Actually, it is the best way to find the most up-to-date procedure.

As an example, look at this tutorial for provisioning developer profile. https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-teach/how-to-prepare/ios-device-provisioning/

You can also read the documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

I ended up deleting every Certificates/Profiles from Keychain. I then imported the Developer Profile from another Mac and voila, it worked.